# ¿Qué es Cross Site Scripting (XSS) y cómo evitarlo?

Tags: javascript, html, seguridad, lenguaje-agnóstico

Al igual que la inyección SQL, este es uno de los ataques
más comunes contra sitios web.

En ocasiones al intentar solucionar nuestros problemas
podemos encontrar e implementar en nuestro código ejemplos
que podrían no ser seguros y acaban vulnerando lo que estamos
haciendo.

Escribí esta pregunta como una referencia interna en este sitio.

**¿Qué es Cross Site Scripting (XSS) y cómo evitarlo?**

Comment: ¿Has visto esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/53591/250?

Comment: Claro, pero pensé que alguien podría compartir tips, buenas prácticas y demás como referencia no solo para php.

Answer (score 1):

XSS es injectar un script en una página que acepte información a través de un formulario. Por ejemplo insertar en un comentario `<script type="text/javascript">alert('hola mundo');</script>` en un formulario para que se inserte el tag en el DOM del explorador de otro usuario que vea nuestro comentario. Así se ejecutaria nuestro código remotamente. La forma de evitarlo es utilizar alguna libreria para hacer "scape" para que los caracteres html no se interpreten como tal.