# Como puedo poner seguridad a las sesiones en php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

ya hice la parte de seguridad y si funciona pero el problema es que no se como hacer que reconozca que la persona ya inicio sesión y puede utilizar esa parte de la pagina [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]perdon por no pner mas imagenes la pagina no me deja

Comment: El código va como texto

Comment: Tu código no es seguro, porque está abierto a [inyecciones SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php) y, además, guardas las [contraseñas sin cifrar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/138517/cifrar-contrase%c3%b1a-php).