# sesiones y seguridad php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

ya hice la parte de seguridad y si funciona pero el problema es que no se como hacer que reconozca que la persona ya inicio sesión y puede utilizar esa parte de la pagina

esta es la parte donde se inicia la sesión en la pagina principal

```
    <?php

     include'configuracion/login.php';

     session_start();
     
     $email = $_SESSION['username'];

    ?>
```

esta es la misma pagina solo que las partes de la publicaciones

```
           <form action="" method="POST">

           <!-- Esto es el Titulo -->
           <br/>
           <div class="titulo"><input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo"  placeholder="Titulo"
            autocomplete="off" required></div>

           
           
           <br/>
            <!-- Esto es la Descripsion del producto -->

           <input type="text" name="descripcion"  placeholder="Descripcion del Producto" autocomplete="off" required>
           
           <br/>
           <br/>

            <!-- Esto el boton file  -->

           <label for="file-upload" class="subir">
           <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i> Subir archivo
           </label>
           <input id="file-upload" onchange='cambiar()' type="file" style='display: none;' 
           name="archivos" required="Es requerido"/>
           <div id="info"></div>

           
           
            <!-- Esto el boton de las publicaciones  -->
            <label for="submit" class="subir2">
            <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i> Publicar
            </label>
            <input id="submit"  type="submit" style='display: none;' 
             name="Enviar" />
            <div id="info"></div>



             </form>  



            <?php 
         
             include'configuracion/seguridad.php';
             include'configuracion/login.php';


            $seguridad = new Seguridad();


            if (isset($_POST['Enviar'])) {
              
               if ($seguridad->getUsuario()==null) {

              echo '<script>alert("Es necesario Iniciar Sesion");</script>';
              
             // header( "refresh:0.5; url=IniciarSesion.php" ); 
         
          }

            }else{

              if ($email==true) {

                echo '<script>alert("ya iniciarte session");</script>';
                
              }


            }
            
            
          


            ?>
        </div>
```

esta es la parte lógica del inicio de sesión

```
<?php 

  include "configuracion/config.php";
  
    

  
  session_start();

      if (isset($_POST['Iniciar'])) {
      
    
      $email = $_POST['email'];

      $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];
      


      $q = "SELECT COUNT(*) as contar FROM vende WHERE Email = '$email' AND Contrasena = '$contrasena'";
      $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,$q);
      $array = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);

      if ($array['contar']>0) {

          $_SESSION['username']=$email;
          
          header( "refresh:0.5; url=Inicio.php" );
        

        
         
      }else{ 

         echo "Datos incorrectos";

      }

     } 





?>
```

y esta es la parte de seguridad

```
<?php 

 
 class Seguridad
 {

    
    private $email=null;

    

    function __construct()
    {
        # arrancamos la sesion
           

        

        if (isset($_SESSION["email"])) $this->$email=$_SESSION["email"]; 
    }

    public function getUsuario(){
        include 'login.php';
        return $email;
    }


    public function addUsuario($email){

        $_SESSION["email"]=$email;
        $this->email=$email;
    }

 }



 ?>
```

y si funciona pero a la hora de iniciar sesión para utilizar las publicaciones me sigue mostrando el mismo mensaje de debe iniciar sesión

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor no repitas preguntas, ya tienes otras dos sobre el mismo tema [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/388564/como-puedo-poner-seguridad-a-las-sesiones-en-php-y-mysql) y [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/388589/como-puedo-hacer-una-sesion-con-seguridad)

Answer (score 0):

El manejo de sesiones normalmente esta condicionado a una vigencia normalmente definida por el proveedor de hosting, es posible que tu sesion este caducando antes de lo que te imaginas, prueba con un dump de la sesion y revisa que la informacion este ahi.

Dado que las estas usando dentro de una clase y dependiendo de la version de php que tengas y de la configuracion de tu proveedor de hosting, podria ser posible que necesites ser especifico dentro de la clase e indicar que se trata de una global:

```
public function addUsuario($email){
    global $_SESSION; // <----
    $_SESSION["email"]=$email;
    $this->email=$email;
}
```

En mi caso, tuve que crear mi propio manejador de sesiones, debido a las restricciones y mis requerimientos de seguridad, en tu caso solo puedo darte algunas recomendaciones:

1.- Si quieres usar las sesiones de php, usalas con una cookie asociada y define la duracion a un tiempo razonable (es muy raro que usuario navegue por horas).

2.- usa cookies para identificar el equipo y el usuario, pero, siempre valida las credenciales.

3.- nunca guardes contraseñas en texto plano en la base de datos, encriptalas antes de guardarlas.

4.- Si te es posible, usa alguna de las opciones para login de algun otro proveedor (ej. facebok) esto lo comento por experiencia propia, hacer un sistema de seguridad "blindado" toma mucho tiempo.

5.- Añade a tu sitio de pruebas un error_log(print_r($_SESSION, true));  // para que te registre en el log el contenido de $_SESSION

Espero que esto te sirva de ayuda.