# problrmas con hashed_password y la contraseña

Tags: php, mysql

Hola buenas tengo un problema con el hash el sal y el hashed_password que cuando me registro y ya e verificado al iniciar sesion la contraseña me pone que es incorrecta

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no sabemos de que estas hablando, falta un monton de contexto, no?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/138517/cifrar-contrase%c3%b1a-php?rq=1

Comment: Holoa Antonio, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son. mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.