# Diferencia de mysqli_real_escape_string vs función definida por el usuario

Tags: php, mysqli

**Hola:**

Estoy realizando un proyecto y me surgió la siguiente duda: ¿ Que diferencia hay entre mysqli_real_scape_string , de una función definida por el usuario ?

Ejemplo función definida por el usuario:

```
function limpiar_datos($data)
{
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

Ejemplo mysqli_real_escape_string:

```
$categoria = isset($_POST['categorias']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['categorias']) : false;
```

¿Es correcto utilizar solamente mysqli_real_escape_string? o bien es conveniente utilizar los dos métodos unidos, por ejemplo:

```
$categoria = isset($_POST['categorias']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($db, limpiar_dartos($_POST['categorias'])) : false;
```

Comment: Yo personalmente usaría sentencias preparada y te evitas todo ese dolor de cabeza. https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php y si quieres más información como evitar la inyección SQL te dejo esta respuesta de SOes https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php/53134#53134

Comment: Añadiendo a lo que ya ha dicho @D.Bulten, yo directamente usaría PDO. Cuanto más anticuada está la tecnología que usas, más fácil es que la vulneren!

Comment: La función que muestras no representa una utilidad más allá de eliminar espacios y modificar algunos caracteres, realmente no previene inyección SQL y, mucho menos, ataques XSS; para más info, comienza por aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53591/como-puedo-proteger-mi-sitio-de-ataques-xss/53592#53592